# Error in activerecord query Yii2

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I declare:

```
$query = Country::find();
```

It works:

```
$countries = $query->orderBy('name')
->offset($pagination->offset)
->limit($pagination->limit)
->all();
```

This does not work:

```
$countries = $query->orderBy('name')
->all();
```

> PHP Warning – yii\base\ErrorException htmlspecialchars() expects
>   parameter 1 to be string, array given

It works:

```
$countries = $query->where(['country.code' => 'AU'])->count();
```

This does not work:

```
$countries = $query->where(['country.population' > 4444444])->all();
```

> Invalid Parameter – yii\base\InvalidParamException
>   Operator ''requires two operands.

I read https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/db-active-record.md but I can not fully understand the idea yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First 'not working' query looks good, please update question with stack trace in this error.

Second:

```
$countries = $query->where(['country.population' > 4444444])->all();
```

You used here `>`, change this to `=>` and it will work. If you want to check if this field is more/less than, you have to pass it like 3 params array:

```
$countries = $query->where(['>', 'country.population', 4444444])->all();
```